# how to install postgresql cleint on windows vm

Tags: postgresql

how to install PostgreSQL client on windows ,please share the link if any or do we have any customized options to configure only client with PostgreSQL installer

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: can you please revert

Comment: Do you mean PostgreSQL client libraries like `libpq.dll` and apps like `psql.exe`?

Comment: I need installer for specific to client(like how we have for oracle and sql database)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It seems that you need to cite yourself: [How do I install just the client tools for PostgreSQL on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854798/how-do-i-install-just-the-client-tools-for-postgresql-on-windows). BTW it is my minimal set of binaries: `libeay32.dll libiconv-2.dll libintl-8.dll libpq.dll ssleay32.dll psql.exe`

Comment: thanks for your responses,so i can conclude that there  no specific installer for client(it comes along with server only and not seperate)

Comment: or is there any customized option to configure only client from the PostgreSQL server