# ImportError "no pq wrapper available" when importing psycopg3

Tags: python, psycopg3

I installed pyscopg3 on my venv using `pip install psycopg[binary]` as per the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/pq.html) but I still get an import error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
no pq wrapper available.
Attempts made:
- couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
- couldn't import psycopg 'binary' implementation: DLL load failed while importing pq: The specified module could not be found.
- couldn't import psycopg 'python' implementation: libpq library not found
```

I'm running a Windows 10 machine. How can I solve this error?

Comment: I'm not qualified to assess whether the answers to the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72245961/error-message-no-pq-wrapper-available-popped-up-when-import-psycopg add anything useful. If they do, please flag for mod attention and request th  two questions to be merged.

Answer (score 35):

I followed the psycopg installation steps from https://pypi.org/project/psycopg/

```
pip install --upgrade pip           # to upgrade pip

pip install "psycopg[binary,pool]"  # to install package and dependencies
```

it worked for me

Comment: For macbook intel this worked for me

Comment: was trying to get it working in intellij without much success. I was able to run this in the venv that was setup for the project and things seem better. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You need to install the command line tools on PostgreSQL on your Windows machine.
Download the full server installer here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

You don't need to install the full server package, only `command line tools` in the installer options will be necessary:

[image]

After the installation, you need to add the PostgreSQL `bin` folder in your `PATH` environnement variable:

hit <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at the same time to get command prompt. Then type `sysdm.cpl`, go to advanced and select "Environment Variables", in PATH add the path to :
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin\` folder (or whatever folder you choose to install the PostreSQL commande line tools).

IMPORTANT: do not forget to close and restart your dev environnement (ie: VSCode, PyCharm, ...) to take the new environnement variable into account.

Note : This answer is related to Windows machine. For Linux the installation of a at least one `postgresql-client-<version>` package will be enough.

related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60369228/5341247

Comment: Did we need to install PostgreSQL commandline tools to use psycopg2 as well? I don't remember needing to install PostgreSQL commandline tools on my prod machine to run pyinstaller-compiled apps that used psycopg2, but now that I've refactored them to use psycopg 3, I needed to follow your advice to make them work again.

Comment: @NickMuise I didn't use psycopg v2 in the past, so I cannot confirm. But to be honnest I don't think psycopg2 dev ships the DLL with their python package... So for me on you prod server you should have the package already installed or a postgresql database already setuped.

Comment: Thanks SuperPoney. Installing the command line tools of PostgreSQL helped me to fix the psycopg[binary] install correctly :)

Comment: I had to restart Windows for it to work. Just reloading the environment was not enough.