# Error message "no pq wrapper available." popped up when import psycopg?

Tags: python

I'm only running my code which the first line is

```
import psycopg
```

and then the ImportError "no pq wrapper available" just popped up.

There's not really a solution i could find anywhere, so that's why i'm asking here.

Comment: make sure your pip over v20.3 and are you running on windows?

Comment: yes, my pip is over v20.3 and running on windows 11, i have added a new PATH that leads to libpq.dll because im using it for python, but seems i get another error `Could not find module 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\bin\libpq.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax`

Answer (score 0):

**There is a new way.**

I was having the exact same issue, and I really couldn't be bothered to hunt it down, as It is working on WSL with IntelliJ on Windows or on WSL with Ubuntu but not in Jupyter lab on Windows (I'll reply back if I find the issue). So, I thought this is a good opportunity to use `import pg8000`. **pg8000** is a pure python implementation for connecting to Postgres, and so far seems similar in operation (I tested it with a cursor and local Postgres). Install pg8000 with `pip3 install pg8000`, then...

**Basic Ingredients**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pg8000 as pg

def db_conn():
    conn = pg.Connection(host='localhost', 
                         database='dev_database', 
                         user='postgres', 
                         password='yourPassword!')
    return conn

# Now you have a connection, query your data with a cursor

conn = db_conn()
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM tab1')
data = cur.fetchall()

# Now 'data' contains your data, or use the new way with conn.run

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Grabbing data from tab1...')

    for row in conn.run('SELECT * FROM tab1'):
        print(row)

    conn.close()
```

The `conn.run` method returns a tuple with a list for every row, but no issue to be read into a pandas DataFrame, and as it's an iterable (no I don't recommend this, but it's a lazy Saturday )

`df = pd.DataFrame([row for row in conn.run('SELECT * FROM journal;')])`

I'll get my coat