# i am trying to use local power shell as cloud power shell (azure power shell vs local power shell )

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, azureshell

i am new
I am trying to use local pc power shell to execute commands like on azure portal power shell.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Svsg.png)
**in my local power shell**
i can login to azure using az login.
az commands are running but i am trying to execute pg_dump --help but it say cannot recognize this command. but az commands are working fine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeToD.png)
**on azure power shell cli**
i can execute all the pg_dumb commands without issue.

please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to install Azure CLI in order to use the same commands on local powershell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli

you need to have also pg_dump and pg_restore command-line utilities installed.

Comment: still not working. pg_dump commands are not working. i am trying to make backup and restore using power shell

Comment: Download command line from below link: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Comment: i did but it works separately as sql shell but not working in power shell. i want to compile these commands in power shell

Comment: Maybe you can create an alias to pg_dump.exe and then you will be able to use it in different location:
PS C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin> Set-Alias -Name pg_dump -Value "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\pg_dump.exe"

PS C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin> cd ..
PS C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14> pg_dump

Answer (score 0):

pg_dump is not part of the Azure CLI but is a [PostgreSQL client application](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html).

Cloud Shell happens to have a lot of packages installed already (i.E. terraform) and apparently pg_dump.

If you want to use it locally on your client you might want to look at installing the corresponding client tools. Maybe this SO thread helps (if you are running Windows): [How do I install just the client tools for PostgreSQL on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854798/how-do-i-install-just-the-client-tools-for-postgresql-on-windows)